# How to replace values according to non-consecutive list of indices in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have been looking for a quick and efficient way to replace values in a given column of a pandas dataframe only if the corresponding indices belong to a list of non-consecutive numbers.
Say non_consecutive_indices_list = [1400, 6571, 14526, 68420, ...] with ca. 30k different values.

1. I have tried to use .iloc but I get an error message:

   ```
   df.iloc[non_consecutive_indices_list, 'column'] = New_Value
   ```

ValueError: Can only index by location with a [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array].

2. Alternatively, I have tried the following:

   ```
   df.iloc[non_consecutive_indices_list].column = New_Value
   ```

But this returns a copy of the original dataframe so I cannot replace the original values.

3. Finally, I have tried to use a for loop, which works, but this is very inefficient and takes forever to replace about 30k values:

   ```
   for i in non_consecutive_indices_list:
       df.loc[i, 'column'] = New_Value
   ```

Any idea how this could be done in a fastest way?

Comment: What about change `iloc` to `loc` like `df.loc[non_consecutive_indices_list, 'column'] = New_Value` ?

Comment: It's strange, because you have 'listlike of integers' in your case. Check the list, may be you have some non-integer values in it.

Comment: Thanks jezrael! You have just saved me hours of future modifications!

Answer (score 2):

Change `iloc` to [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column':list('abcdefghij')})

non_consecutive_indices_list = [2,4,1,6]
df.loc[non_consecutive_indices_list, 'column'] = 'New_Value'
print (df)
      column
0          a
1  New_Value
2  New_Value
3          d
4  New_Value
5          f
6  New_Value
7          h
8          i
9          j
```